# Stove Temperature Control broken

Tags: thermostat, stove

I have a (Simpson Mercury) electric stove - and 2 of the 4 elements do not work properly. They heat up, but it is not possible to set the appropriate temperature for them - they are either on or off.

Does anyone know if I need to simply replace the elements or if there is a thermostat which needs to be replaced ?

Comment: If the elements heat they should be ok the controls for those elements have failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All electric stoves have thermostats that control the heat to the burners. If the burner doesn't cycle on and off when set to 3 or 4 to control the heat then the thermostat is not working properly.